Which characters are valid in a user defined literal?
If I define a UDL like:
template <char... C> auto operator""_myUDL(){return 5;}

then what is the full range of legal arguments to _myUDL?

@some programmer dude: I don't think that's true. I can't do :_myUDL for example

There are suffix for regular literals, so char to form either an integer literal or a floating-point literal.

In this form only something that looks like a very long numeric.

@Red.Wave Doesn't have to be "very long" - 1_myUDL works just fine with OP's declaration.

@Barry yes. "Very long" is not the cannon part. But it can implement big number literals with numeric look. I would use  template<std::array> form for more flexibility, at the expense of string looks.

This form
template <char... C> auto operator""_myUDL()

can only be used for user-defined-integer-literals and user-defined-floating-point-literals.
For integer literals, the possible characters are:

0..9
A..F and a..f
X and x
'

For floating-point literals, the possible characters are:

0..9
A..F and a..f
X and x
'
.
P and p
+ and -

There might be more in the future.

Not accurate enough. Take a look at boost.multi_precision. They have such UDL for the Big Numbers.

it looks like leading - doesn't go into the UDL. like -9_myUDL gives -5. Same with +.

@HeskyFisher -9 is an integer literal 9 with operator - applied to it source.  I believe the only way it is valid in a floating point literal is when it is part of the exponent like 9.0e-5_myUDL

@NathanOliver I see, thanks for the explanation

Missing . for floating point literals.

@Barry Added, thanks.
